# Using H2 database in embedded mode for simple db in production?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, h2

I have a counter java ee singleton which generates id for two specific tasks. Singleton does not persist values across restarts and I want these counters to survive server restarts. So for this purpose am planning to use H2 database in embedded mode to persist the counters. Only a single war will use this counter and hence usage is local.

So is H2(embedded mode) right for this simple task to just store a 2 column single row table in production?

Comment: Asking "is X right for task Y" is too opinion based for SO.  But in any case, using an embedded database for simple persistence (i.e. single resource, no distributed transactions) is a reasonable thing to do

Comment: You may have an issue with not being able to log in to your DB while your war is using it (in embedded mode), but aside from that it is doable.

Comment: As it is noted in many places to avoid using H2 in production, hence wanted to confirm if H2 usage in production is recommended or not?

Comment: I have several production that uses H2 database.

DB sizes are 10-200 GB (per project). for larger DB I use MySQL.

I think that latest releases are very stable and can be used for production.